# Inicializar rowIndex con -1 al buscar un registro en un DataGridView

Tags: c#, variables, datagridview

estaba buscando información por si podia localizar un registro en un DataGridView sin tener que recorrer todo el grid y me encontrado con un usuario que quería localizar un registro concreto en un dataGridView, y me he fijado que en todas las respuestas inicializaban el entero con el que almacenarian el índice del registro con **-1**.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179223/find-a-row-in-datagridview-based-on-column-and-value
Ejemplo:

```
String searchValue = "somestring";
int rowIndex = -1;
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
    {
        rowIndex = row.Index;
        break;
    }
}
```

En practicamente todas la respuestas, la inicializan así, ¿Alguien puede decirme el motivo?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es para saber si se encontró o no el índice, por ejemplo podrías comprobarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
if(rowIndex != -1){ //Encontrado }
```

Por lo que no es necesario que se inicialice en -1, pero es lo más común.